# Getting "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" with google_oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

The URL's seem right (Last updated them yesterday):

[image]

The files too:

**omniauth.rb:**

```
provider :google_oauth2, 'MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
           :scope => 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/'

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI
```

**header.html.erb**

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign in with Google", "auth/google_oauth2" %></li>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#omniauth_create'
```

But I'm getting this:

```
> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request:
> http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a
> registered redirect URI
```

(Twitter and Facebook OmniAuth are working perfectly)

Not sure what is the problem. Any usggestions to fix this?

**EDIT**

I changed the URI to `http`...:

[image]

But still getting the same error.

Comment: Try this answer it worked with me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466634/1770571

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like the request is hitting `http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback`, but your specified redirect URI matching the similar pattern is for `https`. Adding `http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback` to your list of redirects may potentially solve that issue.

**EDIT:** Another potential fix is including a trailing `/` in the corresponding redirect URIs, which appeared to work in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I thought was that too. I added a `http://localhost:3000` redirect and updated omniath.rb. But still getting the same error (please see my **EDIT**).

Comment: @alexchenco Ah, I see. Have you tried adding both `http` and `https` to the URI list? I agree that it looks like you're doing everything right, but I have usually defaulted to adding a both `http` and `https` URIs whenever OAuth is involved. Also, long shot, but have you tried adding trailing `/`'s to the URIs? So potentially four URIs (overkill, yes :) ): `http` and `https`, one each including the trailing frontslash and without it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Add to add a trailing `/`. Very strange, my Rails app doesn't have a trailing `/`, and the example Google provides doesn't include it either.

Comment: @alexchenco Awesome! I don't even want to try to theorize on why because I'll be wrong, but I have run across that same problem more than once, so I default to throwing all possible combos in there. One of these days I'll get more efficient about it :)

Comment: Adding `?close` to the end of redirect uris helped me.

Comment: Wow, soooo much black magic here O.o And nothing worked for me :P

Answer (score 4):

There's a relatively fresh issue with `omniauth-oauth2` gem version `1.4` https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81#issuecomment-151038559

Temporary fix is to downgrade that gem explicitly in the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
```

Comment: they saying to avoid "thank" so i'm gonna say "love you" for such a simple solution :*

Answer (score 0):

[image]

foo

vi config/initializers/omniauth.rb 

`OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'https://localhost:3000'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'google_client_id', 'google_client_secret'
end`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a very simple *copy-paste* solution that worked for me.

I copied whatever I was specifying in my code as `redirectUri` i.e. `"redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:3001/"` and pasted the `value` of this `key` inside the *Google settings* that ask for **Authorized redirect URIs**.  This way I'm ensured that both the parameters are same.

If the `url` was computed, I would `console.log()` it and copy it from the console window before pasting it in for google settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above but didn't work for me.  In the end noticed in my error message my call back was slightly different. I had a users between localhost:3000 and auth.  Not really sure why.

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
```

Changed it, waited 30 mins and it worked.