# Rails google_omniauth2 'error: redirect_uri_mismatch'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, google-developers-console, omniauth-google-oauth2

I have been attempting to add google auth to my signup page and have followed the steps in the [guide](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) but once I sign in to my google account, I get redirected to localhost:3000/# and have the following error in my console:

```
E, [2018-01-02T18:21:05.351019 #57341] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, redirect_uri_mismatch:
```

{
  "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}

I have tried all the solutions in [this existing stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204953/8637931) thread but none of these solutions that have worked for these users have worked for me.

My devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
config.extend_remember_period = true
config.password_length = 2..72
config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
config.sign_out_via = :get



 OmniAuth.config.full_host = Rails.env.production? ? 
  'http://localhost:3000'
    config.omniauth(:facebook,
                  Rails.application.secrets.facebook_app_id,
                  Rails.application.secrets.facebook_api_key,
                  image_size: :large)
     config.omniauth(:google_oauth2,
                  Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
                  Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
                  {:redirect_uri => 
     "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback"}
     )
     require('devise/orm/active_record')
 end
```

routes.rb

```
  r.devise_for(:users,
             only:        :omniauth_callbacks,
             controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: :omniauth})
```

I have also added the following redirect uris to my google developers console:

https://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
https://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback/
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback/

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Try removing the host (`http://localhost:3000`) from `{:redirect_uri => 
     "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback"}`

Comment: And if that doesn't work, replace `redirect_uri` with `callback_path`. That is working for me.

Comment: I understand why this should work but still no dice. Thank you for the attempt though!

Answer (score 0):

My issue turned out to only appear when the `:name` option was added. Once removed, this works just fine like below:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], {
  :scope => "email, profile",
  :prompt => "select_account",
  :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
  :image_size => 50
}
```

Hope to help

Comment: I didn't use any parameters for scope, prompt, or image_size but I added them just to see if it would change anything. Still nothing.